# re.findall does not find some dots

Tags: python, nlp, python-re, lemmatization

I have a file with preprocessed german text [all 39lines have a dot at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XRBP.png)

In order to get rid of some nulls in text I use this code:

```
text_with_nulls = open('lemmatizeAFD', 'r')
text_without_nulls = open('lemmatizeAFD_without_nulls', 'w')
for i in text_with_nulls:
    res = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß\.]+', i)
    for i in res:
        text_without_nulls.write(i)
        text_without_nulls.write(' ')
```

the output file, however, has only 33 dots, but all lemmatized words are in placed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr8X1.png)

Why did some dots disappear? I need them to split sentenses in separate lines later.

I am not very pofessional in `re`, so I assume that something is wrong with `res = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß\.]+', i)`

Comment: If you want to remove the zeroes, why not remove the zeroes instead of extracting everything else? `for i in res: print(re.sub('0+ ?', '', i))` should print the lines with the zeroes removed.